# Area of set-difference

Tags: geometry, measure-theory, metric-spaces

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two open sets in $\mathbb{R}^2$, with $X\subsetneq Y$.

Is it possible that $\text{Area}(Y\setminus X)=0$?

Is it possible that $\text{Area}(Y\setminus Closure[X])=0$?

Comment: what il $Cl[X]$ ?

Comment: The closure of $X$. Fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: can you think of a nonempty closed set of zero area?

Comment: Yes - a point, a line segment, etc. But is it possible that the difference of two open sets be one of these?

Comment: @ErelSegalHalevi: so what happens if you remove a line segment from an open set which contains it?

Comment: Ah, I see... it is still open. So the answer to both my questions is yes.

Comment: @ErelSegalHalevi: That's correct.

Answer (score 1):

$Y = \mathbb{R}^2$

$X = \mathbb{R}^2 - \{0\}$

Answer (score 1):

It is worth noting that the second condition is implied by the first.

If $\operatorname{Area}(Y\setminus X) = 0$, then as $X \subseteq \overline{X}$, we have $Y\setminus\overline{X} \subseteq Y\setminus X$, so

$$\operatorname{Area}\left(Y\setminus\overline{X}\right) \leq \operatorname{Area}(Y\setminus X) = 0$$

and therefore $\operatorname{Area}\left(Y\setminus\overline{X}\right) = 0$. That is,

$$\operatorname{Area}(Y\setminus X) = 0 \Rightarrow \operatorname{Area}\left(Y\setminus\overline{X}\right) = 0.$$

So if you find an example of the first kind, it is automatically an example of the second kind as well. As has already been established, examples of the first kind exist.