# Area of set-difference of special sets

Tags: general-topology, geometry, measure-theory, terminology

In a topological space, call a set $X$ **special** if it is equal to the closure of its own interior (is there a standard term for this?):

$$X = \text{Cl}[\text{Int}[X]]$$

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two special sets in $\mathbb{R}^d$ with $X\subsetneq Y$. Let $m$ be the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^d$.

Is it possible that $m(Y\setminus X) = 0$?

I think that the answer is no. Here is my proof.

---

> Assume that $X\subseteq Y$ and that $m(Y\setminus X) = 0$.
>
> $Y\setminus X = Y \cap X^C \supseteq \text{Int}[Y]\cap X^C$, so:
>
> $$m(\text{Int}[Y]\cap X^C)=0$$
>
> $X$ is closed so its complement $X^C$ is open. Hence $\text{Int}[Y]\cap X^C$ is open. The only open set with zero Lebesgue measure is the empty set (because any other open set contains an open ball with a positive Lebesgue measure). Hence:
>
> $$\text{Int}[Y]\cap X^C = \emptyset$$
>
> Which is equivalent to:
>
> $$\text{Int}[Y] \subseteq X$$
>
> Take the Int of both sides:
>
> $$\text{Int}[Y] \subseteq \text{Int}[X]$$
>
> Take the Cl of both sides and use the fact that they are both special:
>
> $$Y \subseteq X$$
>
> Hence:
>
> $$Y = X$$

---

My questions:

- Is this proof correct?
- Is there a standard name for the property I called "special", which seems very useful?

[This is a followup to [Area of set-difference](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1097442/area-of-set-difference) ]

Comment: Stephen Willard calls them "regularly closed".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These sets are called regular closed sets; the open variant, where a set equals the interior of its closure, is called regular open (see [this glossary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_topology#R)). A set of the form $\operatorname{Cl}\operatorname{Int}(A)$ is always regular closed.

The set of regular open sets is a Boolean algebra (using intersection and a slightly modified union and complement) and are used e.g. in the Stone representation theorem. Quite a few papers are dedicated to regular open and regular closed subsets of topological spaces.

Your proof seems correct, yes.